# Why old data persists in component and how can I reset it

Tags: javascript, angular, ngxs

I fetch data in NGXS state

```
@State<CollectionsStateModel>({
name: 'collections',
defaults: {
 collectionList: [],
 (...),
 isListLoading: true,
 },
 })


@Selector() static collectionList(state: CollectionsStateModel) { 
 return state.collectionList;
}

@Action(GetCollectionListAction)
    getCollectionList(ctx: any) {
        this.collectionService.getCollections().subscribe((response) => {
            ctx.patchState({
                collectionList: response,
                isListLoading: false,
            });
        });
    }
```

Then in the component I get the data and manipulate it: sort it and save to component's variable

```
@Select(CollectionsState.collectionList) collections$!: Observable<IntegratedCollectionExtended[]>; collections: IntegratedCollectionExtended[] | undefined;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.dispatch(new GetCollectionListAction());

        this.collections$.subscribe((collections) => {
            collections.forEach((collection) => {
                collection.isActive = collection.startDate
                    ? new Date(collection.startDate._seconds * 1000) < this.currentTime
                    : collection.isActive;
            });

            collections.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.isActive) return -1;
                return 0;
            });

            collections.sort((a, b) => {
                if (new Date(a.startDate._seconds * 1000) < new Date(b.startDate._seconds * 1000)) return -1;
                if (new Date(a.startDate._seconds * 1000) > new Date(b.startDate._seconds * 1000)) return 1;
                return 0;
            });

            collections.forEach((collection) => {
                if (collection.isListed) this.previewCollections.push(collection);
                this.previewCollections = this.previewCollections.slice(0, 3);
                collection.startDate = new Date(collection.startDate._seconds * 1000).toString();
            });
            this.collections = collections;
        });
    }
```

The data comes with seconds and nanoseconds timestamp so I change it string to display it in the template.
Now everything works fine when I navigate to the component for the first time, but other than that it gets messed up. It seems the string saved on `starDate` persists there.

I `consoled.log` everywhere and get new data in the state, new data in the beginning of ngOnInit, but then it uses previously saved values. Even when I use `this.collections = []` in the beginning of ngOnInit, ngOnDestroy whatever.
Can someone help?

Comment: So my state looks like this:

@State<CollectionsStateModel>({
    name: 'collections',
    defaults: {
        collectionList: [],
        (...)
        isListLoading: true,
    },
})

and there is this selector: 
    @Selector()
    static collectionList(state: CollectionsStateModel) {
        return state.collectionList;
    }

in the component I use:

@Select(CollectionsState.collectionList) collections$!: Observable<IntegratedCollectionExtended[]>;
collections: IntegratedCollectionExtended[] | undefined;

Comment: I just added the code to question. 
So `getCollectionList` updates the state. But still the values in the ngOnInit are correct. Just then they change from timestamp to string. I don't know what causes that. Component gets destroyed so I assume it doesn't hold previous values but then what does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding to my previous comments....

An aspect of the component code that could be looked at is the mutation of the `collections` array and `collection` items. Using `sort` is changing the `store` version of the array, same with directly setting `collection.startDate`

You could use `lodash` `cloneDeep` at the beginning of the subscribe to copy the `collections` object/array, and then use that copy as you please in the component. Might solve the issue, or at least narrowthe problem down

Comment: Thank you, I thought you can't modify state like that without calling a proper method.